# Does Bio.Entrez's efetch() retrieve all metadata of a PubMed article?

Tags: python, biopython, ncbi, pubmed

I wonder whether [Bio.Entrez](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-module.html)'s [`efetch()`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-pysrc.html#efetch) retrieves all metadata of a PubMed article, given a PMID as input. By all metadata, I mean whether PubMed has any more metadata than what `efetch()` retrieves.

---

For example, I see that for the PMID `23954024`, `efetch()` retrieves an abstract that contains a bit less information than the abstract on PubMed's website (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23954024):

`efetch()`:

```
"AbstractText": [
    "Rotator cuff tendinopathy is a common source of shoulder pain characterised by persistent and/or recurrent problems for a proportion of sufferers. The aim of this study was to pilot the methods proposed to conduct a substantive study to evaluate the effectiveness of a self-managed loaded exercise programme versus usual physiotherapy treatment for rotator cuff tendinopathy.", 
    "A single-centre pragmatic unblinded parallel group pilot randomised controlled trial.", 
    "One private physiotherapy clinic, northern England.", 
    "Twenty-four participants with rotator cuff tendinopathy.", 
    "The intervention was a programme of self-managed loaded exercise. The control group received usual physiotherapy treatment.", 
    "Baseline assessment comprised the Shoulder Pain and Disability Index (SPADI) and the Short-Form 36, repeated three months post randomisation.", 
    "The recruitment target was met and the majority of participants (98%) were willing to be randomised. 100% retention was attained with all participants completing the SPADI at three months. Exercise adherence rates were excellent (90%). The mean change in SPADI score was -23.7 (95% CI -14.4 to -33.3) points for the self-managed exercise group and -19.0 (95% CI -6.0 to -31.9) points for the usual physiotherapy treatment group. The difference in three month SPADI scores was 0.1 (95% CI -16.6 to 16.9) points in favour of the usual physiotherapy treatment group.", 
    "In keeping with previous research which indicates the need for further evaluation of self-managed loaded exercise for rotator cuff tendinopathy, these methods and the preliminary evaluation of outcome offer a foundation and stimulus to conduct a substantive study."
],
```

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23954024 : 
    Abstract
    OBJECTIVES:
    Rotator cuff tendinopathy is a common source of shoulder pain characterised by persistent and/or recurrent problems for a proportion of sufferers. The aim of this study was to pilot the methods proposed to conduct a substantive study to evaluate the effectiveness of a self-managed loaded exercise programme versus usual physiotherapy treatment for rotator cuff tendinopathy.

```
DESIGN:
A single-centre pragmatic unblinded parallel group pilot randomised controlled trial.

SETTING:
One private physiotherapy clinic, northern England.

PARTICIPANTS:
Twenty-four participants with rotator cuff tendinopathy.

INTERVENTIONS:
The intervention was a programme of self-managed loaded exercise. The control group received usual physiotherapy treatment.

MAIN OUTCOMES:
Baseline assessment comprised the Shoulder Pain and Disability Index (SPADI) and the Short-Form 36, repeated three months post randomisation.

RESULTS:
The recruitment target was met and the majority of participants (98%) were willing to be randomised. 100% retention was attained with all participants completing the SPADI at three months. Exercise adherence rates were excellent (90%). The mean change in SPADI score was -23.7 (95% CI -14.4 to -33.3) points for the self-managed exercise group and -19.0 (95% CI -6.0 to -31.9) points for the usual physiotherapy treatment group. The difference in three month SPADI scores was 0.1 (95% CI -16.6 to 16.9) points in favour of the usual physiotherapy treatment group.

CONCLUSIONS:
In keeping with previous research which indicates the need for further evaluation of self-managed loaded exercise for rotator cuff tendinopathy, these methods and the preliminary evaluation of outcome offer a foundation and stimulus to conduct a substantive study.
```

(the `OBJECTIVES`, `DESIGN`, `SETTING`, etc. are missing from `efetch()`'s abstract.)

What other metadata does `efetch()` misses, and is there any way to programmatically retrieve the missing information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info is not missing:

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "sample@sample.org"

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id="23954024", rettype="xml")

print(handle.read())
```

Part of the output:

```
<Abstract>
 <AbstractText Label="OBJECTIVES" NlmCategory="OBJECTIVE">Rotator cuff tendinopathy is a common source of shoulder pain characterised by persistent and/or recurrent problems for a proportion of sufferers. The aim of this study was to pilot the methods proposed to conduct a substantive study to evaluate the effectiveness of a self-managed loaded exercise programme versus usual physiotherapy treatment for rotator cuff tendinopathy.</AbstractText>
 <AbstractText Label="DESIGN" NlmCategory="METHODS">A single-centre pragmatic unblinded parallel group pilot randomised controlled trial.</AbstractText>
 <AbstractText Label="SETTING" NlmCategory="METHODS">One private physiotherapy clinic, northern England.</AbstractText>
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend xbello's answer, no, the info is not missing, but a bit hidden.

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id="23954024", rettype="xml")
records = Entrez.read(handle)

for record in records:

    m = record['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']['AbstractText']
    for subsection in m:
        print(subsection.attributes['Label'])
        print(subsection)
```

Truncated output:

> OBJECTIVES
>
> Rotator cuff tendinopathy is a common source of shoulder
> pain characterised by persistent and/or recurrent problems for a
> proportion of sufferers. The aim of this study was to pilot the
> methods proposed to conduct a substantive study to evaluate the
> effectiveness of a self-managed loaded exercise programme versus usual
> physiotherapy treatment for rotator cuff tendinopathy.
>
> DESIGN
>
> A single-centre pragmatic unblinded parallel group pilot randomised
> controlled trial.